# How to pass variable between Chef resource blocks of same recipe

Tags: chef-recipe

We have a Chef recipe with a couple resource blocks. The first resource block is in bash and gets the value of the UUID of a logical volume and stores into variable $uuid.

```
# Get UUID value
bash 'get uuid' do
  cwd "/"
  code <<-EOH
    uuid=$(blkid -o value -s UUID /dev/vg_volgroup/lv_logicalvolume)
  EOH
end
```

We need to pass the variable `$uuid` to our second resource block:

```
# Mount directory, format, update fstab
  mount node['mount_dir'] do
    dump 1
    pass 2
    device #{uuid}
    device_type :uuid
    fstype node['fstype']
    options node['options']
    action [ :mount, :enable]
  end
```

Unfortunately, this is not working. The value of $uuid is not getting passed into the second resource block.

Is there a more proper way to reference $uuid from within the second resource block? Is what I'm asking even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UUID is part of [`filesystem2` Ohai data](https://github.com/chef/ohai/blob/master/lib/ohai/plugins/linux/filesystem.rb):

```
filesystem2:
  by_device:
    /dev/md1:
      ...
      uuid:                f49a3dc8-a0b6-4e1c-8cd3-926fa7d8ee29
```

There is no need to run `blkid` for this.

However, if you really need to do compute something in a block and use it later, you could declare `uuid` variable before the block and use `ruby_block` instead. You can also use node variable inside a ruby block. Anyway, you will be affected by Chef's [two pass model](https://coderanger.net/two-pass/) and it would require further workarounds (like lazy attributes).

There is also a option to use helper method, but since UUID is part of Ohai data, I do not see any reason to even try (in this case).

Comment: Thanks Szymon. I ended up using Ohai as follows and works perfectly: `device node['filesystem2']['by_device']['/dev/mapper/vg_volgroup-lv_logicalvolume']['uuid']`